# How could i use the count() function in my function?

Tags: python

I have made a function which to filtering the vowels in a string.

```
def number_of_vowels(stringPara):
    vowels = ['u', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'i']
    return list(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, stringPara))
print(number_of_vowels("Technical University"))
```

Now I need to count every single vowel the string contain by count() function. But I have no idea how to use it when I have the lambda function.

Comment: Your current code doesn't run. Please fix it before trying to add to it. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: You're talking about [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), right? Why not use `enumerate` instead? Is this homework? If so please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Comment: What's the point of using `lambda`, `filter()`, and `list()`, just to avoid a simple list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Counter` for this:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter("Technical University")
vowels = ['u', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'i']

print({k: v for k, v in counter.items() if k in vowels})
# {'e': 2, 'i': 3, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def number_of_vowels(stringPara):
    vowels = ['u', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'i']
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, stringPara)))
print(number_of_vowels("Technical University"))
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: actually thank you for your answer, but what i need is the function will specify the number of every single vowel.
Ex: e:2, i:3, a:1, u:1

Answer (score 0):

It returns the total count and count per vowel:

```
def number_of_vowels(stringPara):
    vowels = ['u', 'e', 'o', 'a', 'i']
    f = list(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, stringPara))
    return(len(f), {v: f.count(v) for v in vowels if f.count(v)>0})

print(number_of_vowels("Technical University"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
from collections import Counter


def numberOfVowels(param):
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
    result = list(filter(lambda x: x in vowels, param))
    return result, dict(Counter(result))


print(numberOfVowels('Technical University'))


# Output:
# (['e', 'i', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'i'], {'e': 2, 'i': 3, 'a': 1})
```